# How can I upload files in spring-integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to upload a file, but I still get a "Could not convert request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for expected type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]" exception

How can a resolve this problem?

```
    private RequestMapping createMappingFile(HttpMethod[] method, String... path) {
        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setMethods(method);
        requestMapping.setConsumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
        requestMapping.setProduces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns(path);
        return requestMapping;
    }

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpPostFileUpload() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(httpPostGateFileUpload())
                .channel("http.file.upload.channel").handle("fileEndpoint", "upload").get();
    }
    @Bean
    public MessagingGatewaySupport httpPostGateFileUpload() {
        // @RequestMapping
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway handler = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway();
        handler.setRequestMapping(createMappingFile(new HttpMethod[]{HttpMethod.POST}, "/api/file/upload"));
        handler.setStatusCodeExpression(fileParser().parseExpression("T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).BAD_REQUEST"));
        handler.setRequestPayloadType(ResolvableType.forClass(MultipartFile.class));
        handler.setHeaderMapper(fileHeaderMapper());
        return handler;
    }
```

FileEndpoint:

```
 public Message<?> upload(Message<MultipartFile>msg) {

        MultipartFile file = msg.getPayload();

        UserDetails loggedUser = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        Optional<User> opUser = userRepository.findByUsername(loggedUser.getUsername());

        User user = opUser.orElseThrow(()->new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"User not found"));

        long date = new Date().getTime();

        File convertFile = new File(resourcePath+date+"_"+file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(convertFile);
            fout.write(file.getBytes());
            fout.close();
...
```

I will push the file into a directory.
Exception:

````
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Could not convert request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for expected type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] and content type [multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------525212308988156732836650;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.extractRequestBody(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:513) ~[spring-integration-http-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read a [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#http-inbound) on the matter:

> The HTTP inbound endpoint locates a `MultipartResolver` in the context if one has a bean name of `multipartResolver` (the same name expected by Spring’s `DispatcherServlet`). If it does locate that bean, the support for multipart files is enabled on the inbound request mapper. Otherwise, it fails when it tries to map a multipart file request to a Spring Integration Message. For more on Spring’s support for `MultipartResolver`, see the Spring Reference Manual.

There is also a sample about [multipart support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/multipart-http).